# Loading a localized pathForResource works on iOS simulator, but fails on device

Tags: ios, localization, ios-simulator, nsbundle

I am trying to load a localized HTML file from the `mainBundle` in iOS 9. The localized files are both named "help.html", and are located in the "de.lproj" and "en.lproj" directories, respectively.

If I am running this code snippet on the simulator (iOS 9.2), it returns the correct `indexPath`, but when I run it on the device (iOS 9.2), it returns nil.

```
NSArray* availableLocalizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
NSArray* userPreferred = [NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:availableLocalizations forPreferences:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];
NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"help" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:[userPreferred objectAtIndex:0]];
```

I already checked and confirmed that the files are existing in the app bundle deployed to the device, and that the filenames (including upper/lowercasing) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behavior of `NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray` changed from iOS 8.4 to 9.0.

Example: I have selected "Austria" as region, and "German" as language.

- iOS 8.4 returns only one preferredLocalization "de".
- iOS 9.0 returns two - "de_AT" and "de".

For "de_AT", `NSBundle pathForResource` cannot find the "de" localization, and returns nil.

Fixed with this (ideally unnecessary) workaround:

```
NSArray* availableLocalizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
NSArray* userPreferred = [NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:availableLocalizations forPreferences:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];

NSString *indexPath;
for (NSString *locale in userPreferred) {
    indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hilfe" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:locale];
    if (indexPath) break;
}
```